# Using jQuery move new children in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am creating a HTML form for data entry that contains a couple of textboxes and function buttons.

There is also an add button that copies (clones) from a DIV template (id: w) for each "row" and appends to the end of the main DIV (id: t). On each row, there is a "X" button to remove the row and two arrow buttons to visually move the "row" up and down in the DOM.

The form is dynamically created from a database and the elements already on the page when the page is loaded and using jQuery 3.4.1, for the selecting and most of the DOM manipulation using the functionality of each rows buttons.

The "rows" are added to the container DIV and the elements are renamed depending on the counter which is expected. The "X" button deletes the "row", and moves all pre-existing rows up and down in the container DIV.

But for some unknown reason any new rows that are created I have to press the "up" button twice. The "down" button for the bottom row, is redundant and not functional.

I think it might have to do with the previousSibling and nextSibling returning the wrong Object type and causing a problem and failing the first time.

Any thoughts on how to fix or improve this functionality?

```js
var rr = $("[id^=l]").length;

$(".data-up").click(function() {
  var e = $(this).first().parent().parent().get(0);
  moveUp(e);
});

$(".data-down").click(function() {
  var e = $(this).parent().parent().get(0);
  moveDown(e);
});

$(".remove").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

function add() {
  rr += 1;
  var a = $("#w").clone(true, true).removeAttr('id').removeAttr('style');
  a.attr("datarow", "row" + rw);
  a.find("input[data-field='l']").attr("id", "l" + rr).attr("name", "l" + rr).removeAttr("data-field");
  a.find("input[data-field='s']").attr("id", "s" + rr).attr("name", "s" + rr).removeAttr("data-field");
  a.appendTo("#t");
}

function moveUp(e) {
  if (e.previousSibling) {
    if (e.previousSibling === e.parentNode.children[0]) {} else {
      e.parentNode.insertBefore(e, e.previousSibling);
    }
  }
}

function moveDown(e) {
  if (e === e.parentNode.children[e.parentNode.children.length - 1]) {} else {
    e.parentNode.insertBefore(e.nextSibling, e);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" ID="p" onclick="add();">Add</button>

<div id="t">
</div>


<div class="form-group row" id="w" style="display:none;" datarow="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1"><input name="s" class="form-control txt-s col-form-label" id="s" type="text" readonly="true" data-field="s"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"><input name="l" class="form-control txt-l" id="l" type="text" data-field="l"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button class="btn btn-danger mr-1 remove" type="button">X</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info mr-1 data-up" type="button">↑</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info data-down" type="button">↓</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet doesn't work, but in general, `xSibling` gives you the closest sibling _node_, whether it's an element or textnode. Use `xElementSibling` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery - use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the current parent of the button. The find the [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) or the [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) sibling. If the sibling exists use [`.insertBefore()`](https://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) or [`.insertAfter()`](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) to move the current parent before or after the sibling:

```js
var rr = $("[id^=l]").length;

$(".data-up").click(function(e) {
  var current = $(this).closest('.form-group'); // find the current parent
  var target = current.prev(); // find the relevant sibling
  
  if(target.length) { // if sibling exists
    current.insertBefore(target); // insert the current item above it
  }
});

$(".data-down").click(function() {
  var current = $(this).closest('.form-group'); // find the current parent
  var target = current.next(); // find the next sibling
  
  if(target.length) { // if the next sibling exists
    current.insertAfter(target); // insert the current item after it
  }
});

$(".remove").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

function add() {
  rr += 1;
  var a = $("#w").clone(true, true).removeAttr('id').removeAttr('style');
  a.attr("datarow", "row" + rr);
  a.find("input[data-field='l']").attr("id", "l" + rr).attr("name", "l" + rr).removeAttr("data-field");
  a.find("input[data-field='s']").attr("id", "s" + rr).attr("name", "s" + rr).removeAttr("data-field");
  a.appendTo("#t");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" ID="p" onclick="add();">Add</button>

<div id="t">
</div>


<div class="form-group row" id="w" style="display:none;" datarow="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1"><input name="s" class="form-control txt-s col-form-label" id="s" type="text" readonly="true" data-field="s"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"><input name="l" class="form-control txt-l" id="l" type="text" data-field="l"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button class="btn btn-danger mr-1 remove" type="button">X</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info mr-1 data-up" type="button">↑</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info data-down" type="button">↓</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### What's wrong in your code

The problem with the up button is `e.previousSibling === e.parentNode.children[0]` - the 1st element is always the first item in the collection, so this blocks you from moving an item above it. All you have to check is if there is a `previousSibling` for up, and `nextSibling` for down.

**Fixed code + comments:**

```js
var rr = $("[id^=l]").length;

$(".data-up").click(function() {
  var e = $(this).parent().parent().get(0); // first() is redundant - this is the only element in the collection
  moveUp(e);
});

$(".data-down").click(function() {
  var e = $(this).parent().parent().get(0);
  moveDown(e);
});

$(".remove").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

function add() {
  rr += 1;
  var a = $("#w").clone(true, true).removeAttr('id').removeAttr('style');
  a.attr("datarow", "row" + rr);
  a.find("input[data-field='l']").attr("id", "l" + rr).attr("name", "l" + rr).removeAttr("data-field");
  a.find("input[data-field='s']").attr("id", "s" + rr).attr("name", "s" + rr).removeAttr("data-field");
  a.appendTo("#t");
}

function moveUp(e) {
  if (e.previousSibling) { // just check if there's a previous sibling
    e.parentNode.insertBefore(e, e.previousSibling);
  }
}

function moveDown(e) {
  if (e.nextSibling) { // just check if there's a next sibling
    e.parentNode.insertBefore(e.nextSibling, e);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" ID="p" onclick="add();">Add</button>

<div id="t">
</div>


<div class="form-group row" id="w" style="display:none;" datarow="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1"><input name="s" class="form-control txt-s col-form-label" id="s" type="text" readonly="true" data-field="s"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"><input name="l" class="form-control txt-l" id="l" type="text" data-field="l"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button class="btn btn-danger mr-1 remove" type="button">X</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info mr-1 data-up" type="button">↑</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info data-down" type="button">↓</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou @Ori, appreciate the feedback. My question would be why didn't my code work in the first place? If I know that my parent DIV is going to two levels up, couldn't I use .parent().parent() specifically?